# How to use Tortoisesvn library?

Tags: ruby

I can't get diff from the subversion because it recognize the file that I'm commited is a binary file, so i need to use some functions in Tortoisesvn's library to compare. But I don't know how to use it :( . Please help! thanks :D

Comment: Better ask "How do I configure a custom format diff so that I get a useful diff display in Tortoise". You don't want to use the library, you want to get a useful diff. At least using the lib functions is not the solution I'd come up with.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file is it? 
Which external compare tool are you using?

If all else fails ... use the [command line](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html).